# Generate Public Key of GGH Cryptosystems

Tags: cryptography

I have a question for the algorithm gen public key of The Goldreich–Goldwasser–Halevi (GGH) lattice-based cryptosystem.
GenKey Algorithm as described in the paper:

Pick a matrix $R'$ which is uniformly distributed in $\{-l,\ldots,l\}$ and then compute $R = R' + k\cdot I$. Then we have $R$ a private basis. And $I$ know a basis of the lattice is linearly independent vectors.

I want to know why $R$ is the basis of lattice when it maybe isn't linearly independent vectors?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GGH_encryption_scheme

Comment: Did you read the next sentence?  _The larger
the value of $k$ is, this process generates a basis with smaller dual orthogonality factor, so
it may be possible to choose a larger value of $\sigma$_ So it's try and find one.

Comment: @kelalaka Thank you so much and i have another question. The once mothod gen private basis is choose a matrix R which is uniformly distributed in {- l,.., +l} for some integer bound l. R is choose random, so how can i make sure det(R) is non-zero to inverse R? –